# Build multiple apps with different assets but using the same code

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am currently changing my apps, made with Swift and Java, to Flutter, however, right now I have 5 Apps for android and iOS, all using the same code (5 in Swift, 5 in Java), and, for each one I have different assets, like images, strings, API url's etc. In case of an iOS app I was currently creating different Targets on XCode, with different user-defined variables that i use in the code, and then I chose which target I want to build and send to the corespondent iTunesConnect app. In android I do more or less the same, but using Android flavors.

My doubt is how can I do this in flutter without being forced to create a different Flutter project for each app I want to build.

Any ideas on what approach should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a custom build script that creates a symlink depending on the flavor name

From my [Grinder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/grinder) build script

```
Future<void> _setTenant(Tenant tenant) async {
  const symlinkPath = 'assets/tenant';
  final link = Link(symlinkPath);

  if (link.existsSync() &&
      link.targetSync() == '../assets/${tenant.identifier}') {
    return;
  }
  if (link.existsSync()) {
    link.updateSync('../assets/${tenant.identifier}');
  } else {
    Link(symlinkPath).createSync('../assets/${tenant.identifier}');
  }
}
```

`Tenant` is a custom class and `Tenant.identifier` returns a string that is valid as directory/symlink name.

I created https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21682 to get direct support for that in Flutter.